# backbone marionette how to fetch data from api

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Im new to BB and marionette , after reading a lot of document on line im trying to build something simple.. 
I have a model with the user information , however I want to get the user list from the server, how do I fetch the data?

```
  ContactManager.module("Entities", function(Entities, ContactManager, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
  Entities.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phoneNumber:''
   },
   initialize: function(){
        console.log('This model has been initialized.');
    }
  });

  Entities.ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Contact,
    url: 'get_all_scan_for_user'
  });

  var contacts;

  var initializeContacts = function(){
   /* contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection([
      { id: 1, firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Arten", phoneNumber: "555-0184" },
      { id: 2, firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Brigham", phoneNumber: "555-0163" },
      { id: 3, firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Campbell", phoneNumber: "555-0129" }
    ]);*/
    contacts = new Entities.ContactCollection();
    contacts.fetch;
  };

  var API = {
    getContactEntities: function(){
      if(contacts === undefined){
        initializeContacts();
      }
      return contacts;
    }
  };

  ContactManager.reqres.setHandler("contact:entities", function(){
    return API.getContactEntities();
  });
});
```

and my controller just call the request

```
var contacts = ContactManager.request("contact:entities");
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: in this line contacts.fetch; fetch is a method so change to contacts.fetch(), you can provide url in there or in the collection extension

Answer (score 0):

1. `contacts.fetch` => `contacts.fetch()`
2. can **url: 'get_all_scan_for_user'** get the contact list?
3. `API.getContactEntities()` will always return the same contact list. 
   I should be

   `getContactEntities: function(){
     if(contacts === undefined){
       initializeContacts();
     }
     contacts.fetch();
     return contacts;
   }`

Comment: Thanks for you help, yes I fix the first problem, the url does return the correct data (ignore the name) , I added you code , but I think I need to change my controller as well, thanks for your help